# How to style every first letter in a paragraph that is not a link

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am currently styling every first letter of a paragraph that follows a heading 3 with the following code, to make them stand out:

```
.someClass h3+p:first-letter{
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Now, I want to exclude all links ("a"-tags) from the selection. I looked into the .not() selector, but

```
.someClass h3+p:not(a):first-letter{
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

is not working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Where is a link. Inside P tag?

Comment: Yes, I want to style <p>Some text</p> (the first letter S bigger), but not <p><a>Some text</a></p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's debug by breaking down your current selector in English:
`.someClass h3+p:not(a):first-letter`

- `.someClass h3` - select the h3 element inside `.someClass` element
- `.someClass h3+p` - select the p element immediately after h3 inside `.someClass`
- `.someClass h3+p:not(a)` - select the p element that's not an anchor element--

We can stop right there - a `<p>` element will never also be an `<a>` because an element can't have multiple tags. Since you're actually trying to affect an `<a>` INSIDE the `<p>`, a `:not()` selector isn't applicable here.

Fortunately, there is another solution - a little bit of an out-of-the-box one: if you change your problematic `<a>` elements that start the `<p>` to become block-level elements (using `display: inline-block` to preserve the intended layout), they won't be affected by their parent's `first-letter` rule anymore.

Here's how that works:

```css
.someClass h3+p:first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.someClass h3+p a:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <p>Paragraph Text</p>

  <h3>H3</h3>
  <p><a href="#">Paragraph</a> Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a pretty nice solution! Thanks for the good explanation!